# Convert pd dataframe into list

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, python-3.7

I've this txt input:

```
["A" "B" "C" "D"]
[8 3 6 11]
[5 7 4 3]
14
```

I read the file by using:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", header = None, engine = 'python')
```

Then, I would like to convert this dataframe into lists.
I've tried to do this:

```
L = df[0].iloc[0]
>>> '["A" "B" "C" "D"]'
```

But then, if I want to get the first value, the output is

```
L[0]

>>> '['
```

I've already tried to do

```
ast.literal_eval(L)
```

without sucess. I get:

```
['ABCD']
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: So what would you do with the fourth row of your input, "14"?

Comment: assign it into a variable

Comment: What do you mean assign it to a variable? Could you put the expected dataframe for the corresponding input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['new'] = df[0].str.strip('[]').str.split()
print (df)
                   0                   new
0  ["A" "B" "C" "D"]  ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
1         [8 3 6 11]         [8, 3, 6, 11]
2          [5 7 4 3]          [5, 7, 4, 3]
3                 14                  [14]
```

If mixed data are necessary - `list`s with scalar(s) add [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for apply solution only for values starting by `[` checked by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['new'] = df[0].mask(df[0].str.startswith('['), df[0].str.strip('[]').str.split())
print (df)
                   0                   new
0  ["A" "B" "C" "D"]  ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
1         [8 3 6 11]         [8, 3, 6, 11]
2          [5 7 4 3]          [5, 7, 4, 3]
3                 14                    14
```